# shiny conditionalPanel update problem with output.table-condition

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build an app that displays tables for different years. In some years some tables do not exist. I solved this with conditionalPanel and the condition that the tables exist. This works at first. The problem is that it doesn't work once a table is retrieved that doesn't exist. You can try this on this test page (http://46.231.205.192/Tests/). After opening the app, one table per year is visible. If you go to the next table with >, the error message for 2021 is correctly displayed at the bottom. If you then go back <, the error continues to be displayed, although the table for 2021 exists in that case.

I think the problem arises from `conditionalPanel` with `output.Table_2021` but I can't fix it.

Can you see a solution?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

Table_1 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 3, US = 3.5, FR = 4, IT = 2, male = 0, female = 1)
Table_2 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 2, US = 2.5, FR = 3, IT = 1, male = 1, female = 2)


Table_1_2021 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 4, US = 4.5, FR = 5, IT = 3, male = 3, female = 10)
# in 2021 the Table_2 is missing 

tabnames <- c("Table_1", "Table_2")

# Columns
kopfvariablen <- c("region", "sex")
default_vars <- c("region")


# Shiny ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div("Tables")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,  tags$style(".well {background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #ffffff}"),
       a(br(), br(), br(), br()),
       checkboxInput(
         inputId = "year_2022",
         label = "Tabs: 2022",
         value = TRUE),
       checkboxInput(
         inputId = "year_2021",
         label = "Tabs: 2021",
         value = TRUE)
),
    mainPanel(
      align = "center",    
      actionButton("prevBin", "<", class="btn btn-success"),  
      actionButton("nextBin", ">", class="btn btn-success"),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataset",
        label = "",
        choices = tabnames, 
        width = "60%"),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.year_2022 == 1  ",
        DT::dataTableOutput("Table_2022")),
      conditionalPanel(inline = T,
        condition = "input.year_2021 == 1 && output.Table_2021", # I think the problem comes with this line.
       DT::dataTableOutput('Table_2021')),
      conditionalPanel(inline = T, 
                       condition = "input.year_2021 == 1 && output.Table_2021 == null",
                       h4("[This Question was not asked in 2021.]", align = "left", style = "color:grey"))
  )
  ))

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
# "next" and "previous" buttons  
  output$prevBin <- renderUI({
    actionButton("prevBin", 
                 label = "Previous")
  })
  output$nextBin <- renderUI({
    actionButton("nextBin", 
                 label = "Next")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$prevBin, {
    current <- which(tabnames == input$dataset)
    if(current > 1){
      updateSelectInput(session, "dataset",
                        choices = as.list(tabnames),
                        selected = tabnames[current - 1])
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$nextBin, {
    current <- which(tabnames == input$dataset)
    if(current < length(tabnames)){
      updateSelectInput(session, "dataset",
                        choices = as.list(tabnames),
                        selected = tabnames[current + 1])
    }
  })
  
 # Tables 2022 -----
output$Table_2022 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # Data with names from input
    data <- get(input$dataset)
    data_fin <- data[,1:7]

 #subheader as list
   subheader <- list()
   subheader <- c(subheader, "US", "FR", "IT")
   subheader <- c(subheader, "male", "female")
    
 # The header
   topheader_txt <- "tr(th(rowspan = 2, 'Values'), th(rowspan = 2, 'Total') , th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 3, 'region'), th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 2, 'sex')"
   topheader <- parse(text=paste0(topheader_txt, ")"))
   
   #Container for topheader and subheader
   sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
     class = 'display',
     thead(
       eval(topheader),
       tr(lapply(rep(subheader, 1), th))
       )
     )
   )
   
  
    # Table with container
    DT::datatable(data_fin, 
                  container = sketch, 
                  rownames = F)
  })

# Tables 2021 -----
output$Table_2021 <- DT::renderDataTable({

  #Daten aus Auswahl

    data <- get(paste0(input$dataset, "_2021"))

    data_fin <- data[,1:7]
    
    #subheader list
    subheader <- list()
    subheader <- c(subheader, "US", "FR", "IT")
    subheader <- c(subheader, "male", "female")
    
    topheader_txt <- "tr(th(rowspan = 2, 'Values'), th(rowspan = 2, 'Total') , th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 3, 'region'), th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 2, 'sex')"
    topheader <- parse(text=paste0(topheader_txt, ")"))
    
    #Container for topheader and subheader
    sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        eval(topheader),
        tr(lapply(rep(subheader, 1), th))
          )
       )
    )
    
    js <- c(
      "function(settings){",
      "  var datatable = settings.oInstance.api();",
      "  var table = datatable.table().node();",
      "  var caption = '2021'",
      "  $(table).append('<caption style=\"caption-side: top-right; text-align: center; margin: 8px 0; font-size: 2em\">' + caption + '</caption>');",
      "}"
    )
    
    # Table with container
    DT::datatable(data_fin, 
                  container = sketch, 
                  rownames = F,
                  caption = tags$caption(
                    style="caption-side: bottom; text-align: left; margin: 8px 0;"
                  ),
                  extensions = c('Buttons'), 
                  options = list(initComplete = JS(js))
    )
})
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution comes with:   `outputOptions(output, "Table_2021", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` in the server function.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

Table_1 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 3, US = 3.5, FR = 4, IT = 2, male = 0, female = 1)
Table_2 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 2, US = 2.5, FR = 3, IT = 1, male = 1, female = 2)


Table_1_2021 <- data.frame(Antworten = "mean", Total = 4, US = 4.5, FR = 5, IT = 3, male = 3, female = 10)
# in 2021 the Table_2 is missing 

tabnames <- c("Table_1", "Table_2")

# Columns
kopfvariablen <- c("region", "sex")
default_vars <- c("region")


# Shiny ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div("Tables")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,  tags$style(".well {background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #ffffff}"),
       a(br(), br(), br(), br()),
       checkboxInput(
         inputId = "year_2022",
         label = "Tabs: 2022",
         value = TRUE),
       checkboxInput(
         inputId = "year_2021",
         label = "Tabs: 2021",
         value = TRUE)
),
    mainPanel(
      align = "center",    
      actionButton("prevBin", "<", class="btn btn-success"),  
      actionButton("nextBin", ">", class="btn btn-success"),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataset",
        label = "",
        choices = tabnames, 
        width = "60%"),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.year_2022 == 1  ",
        DT::dataTableOutput("Table_2022")),
      conditionalPanel(inline = T,
        condition = "input.year_2021 == 1 && output.Table_2021", # I think the problem comes with this line.
       DT::dataTableOutput('Table_2021')),
      conditionalPanel(inline = T, 
                       condition = "input.year_2021 == 1 && output.Table_2021 == null",
                       h4("[This Question was not asked in 2021.]", align = "left", style = "color:grey"))
  )
  ))

server = function(input, output, session) {

outputOptions(output, "Table_2021", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) # Solution
  
# "next" and "previous" buttons  
  output$prevBin <- renderUI({
    actionButton("prevBin", 
                 label = "Previous")
  })
  output$nextBin <- renderUI({
    actionButton("nextBin", 
                 label = "Next")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$prevBin, {
    current <- which(tabnames == input$dataset)
    if(current > 1){
      updateSelectInput(session, "dataset",
                        choices = as.list(tabnames),
                        selected = tabnames[current - 1])
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$nextBin, {
    current <- which(tabnames == input$dataset)
    if(current < length(tabnames)){
      updateSelectInput(session, "dataset",
                        choices = as.list(tabnames),
                        selected = tabnames[current + 1])
    }
  })
  
 # Tables 2022 -----
output$Table_2022 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # Data with names from input
    data <- get(input$dataset)
    data_fin <- data[,1:7]

 #subheader as list
   subheader <- list()
   subheader <- c(subheader, "US", "FR", "IT")
   subheader <- c(subheader, "male", "female")
    
 # The header
   topheader_txt <- "tr(th(rowspan = 2, 'Values'), th(rowspan = 2, 'Total') , th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 3, 'region'), th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 2, 'sex')"
   topheader <- parse(text=paste0(topheader_txt, ")"))
   
   #Container for topheader and subheader
   sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
     class = 'display',
     thead(
       eval(topheader),
       tr(lapply(rep(subheader, 1), th))
       )
     )
   )
   
  
    # Table with container
    DT::datatable(data_fin, 
                  container = sketch, 
                  rownames = F)
  })

# Tables 2021 -----
output$Table_2021 <- DT::renderDataTable({

  #Daten aus Auswahl

    data <- get(paste0(input$dataset, "_2021"))

    data_fin <- data[,1:7]
    
    #subheader list
    subheader <- list()
    subheader <- c(subheader, "US", "FR", "IT")
    subheader <- c(subheader, "male", "female")
    
    topheader_txt <- "tr(th(rowspan = 2, 'Values'), th(rowspan = 2, 'Total') , th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 3, 'region'), th(class = 'dt-center', colspan = 2, 'sex')"
    topheader <- parse(text=paste0(topheader_txt, ")"))
    
    #Container for topheader and subheader
    sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        eval(topheader),
        tr(lapply(rep(subheader, 1), th))
          )
       )
    )
    
    js <- c(
      "function(settings){",
      "  var datatable = settings.oInstance.api();",
      "  var table = datatable.table().node();",
      "  var caption = '2021'",
      "  $(table).append('<caption style=\"caption-side: top-right; text-align: center; margin: 8px 0; font-size: 2em\">' + caption + '</caption>');",
      "}"
    )
    
    # Table with container
    DT::datatable(data_fin, 
                  container = sketch, 
                  rownames = F,
                  caption = tags$caption(
                    style="caption-side: bottom; text-align: left; margin: 8px 0;"
                  ),
                  extensions = c('Buttons'), 
                  options = list(initComplete = JS(js))
    )
})
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```